# OpenIddict configuration

Tags: asp.net-core, openiddict

I'm in need of a detailed explanation on how I should configure OpenIddict in ASP.NET Core 7.
I have been looking at the available examples and documentation for a week now.
But I do not understand why some examples have ~400 lines of code and others have ~40, in their controller or endpoint implementations.

To make my use case and problem more specific:

Server side:

- ASP.NET Core 7

  - Using minimal APIs
- EF Core 7
- PostgreSQL

Clients:

- Blazor WASM or Angular

  - Decision not yet made
  - A skeleton Blazor WASM app created
- Mobile apps (native iOS and Android)

I also need to refresh the token, and the user to access and modify the profile data.

I will also need to use other authentication providers (e.g.: Apple, Google).

I read the [official docs](https://documentation.openiddict.com/) and tried to undertand the [examples](https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-samples/).

*Edit: I tried the Balosar and Zirku examples.*

It left me more confused.

So my goal would be to understand why I need to add and how to configure certain services to achive the functionality described above.

Also, how to implement the needed endpoints, can I do it in minimal APIs, or do I have to stick with the controllers, or add views?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.